Does the limit of $\binom{n}{np} p^{np} (1-p)^{n(1-p)}$ exist when $n\rightarrow +\infty$ with a constant $p\in [0, 1]$?
Does the limit of $\binom{n}{np} p^{np} (1-p)^{n(1-p)}$ exist when $n\rightarrow +\infty$ with a constant $p\in [0, 1]$?
Intuitively, we consider a box with a proportion $p$ of balls being red and the rest blue. It seems that as the total number of samples $n$ becomes infinitely large, the probability of picking $np$ red ball should approach the probability $1$, potentially suggesting that the limit is also $1$.
However, I don't know whether there is a formal proof. Moreover, it seems this question has something with the Law of Large Numbers (LLN). But LLN deals with probability, while this is just the limit of a function of $n$.

@CharlesGreen $p$ should be in $[0, 1]$ according to the probability intuition.

Hint: What's the standard deviation of the number of red balls? Roughly how likely is it that the number will be exactly its mode?

J.G. is suggesting that you (heuristically) apply the central limit theorem here, rather than the LLN: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem

You have an issue when $np$ is not an integer.  But let's consider $p=\frac12$ and $n$ is even.  Then the probability of sampling exactly half red when $n=2$ is $0.5$ and when $n=2000000$ is about $0.000564$ and more generally asymptotically $\sqrt{\frac2{\pi ,n}}$.

As the number of samples $n$ increases to infinity, the distribution of the number of red balls picked, $\sum_i X_i / n$, converges in distribution to $N(p, p(1-p))$. That is, $\sum_i X_i$ converges to $N(np, n^2 p(1-p))$. The standard deviation is too large ($n\sqrt{p(q-p)} \rightarrow \infty$) to keep the random number around the expectation. Is the intuition right? @J.G.

Your $n^2$ should be $n$, but that's the idea. There exists a constant $c$ for which the exactly-modal probability is asymptotic to $c/\sqrt{n}$.

I'd use Stirling's approximation: $n! \sim n^ne^{-n}\sqrt{2\pi n}.$
Note that ${n \choose np}\sim\frac{n^n e^{-n}\sqrt{2\pi n}}{(np)^{np}e^{-np}\sqrt{2\pi n p} (n\bar{p})^{n\bar{p}}e^{-n\bar{p}}\sqrt{2\pi n \bar{p}}}=\frac{1}{p^{np}\bar{p}^{n\bar{p}} \sqrt{2\pi n\bar{p}}\sqrt{p}}.$ By $\bar{x}$ I mean $1-x$.
Multiply this with $p^{np}\bar{p}^{n \bar{p}}$, we get some $\sqrt{n}$ inside the denominator, hence the limit should be zero.
